# I can't create cesium asset with react and axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, cesiumjs

I'm trying to upload .las file to cesium.com.
I'm using reactjs.
In cesium rest api, you have to create an asset on cesium, then upload the file to S3, then tell cesium where the file is on s3.
They give example in nodejs here : https://cesium.com/learn/ion/ion-upload-rest/

I manage to get my assets list with axios and react like this :

```
try {
        const resp = await axios.get('https://api.cesium.com/v1/assets', {
            headers: {
                'authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            },
            json: true
        });
        console.log(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
```

But when I try to create an assets like this :

```
try {
        const resp = await axios.post('https://api.cesium.com/v1/assets', {
            headers: {
                'authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            },
            json: true,
            body: postBody
        });
        console.log(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
```

I get a : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()

I have already double check my accessToken, it's set on : assets:list, assets:read, assets:write, geocode, profile:read, tokens:read, tokens:write
So basically every thing should be allowed with this token.

Any body has an idea what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: The exemple they give in nodejs is working fine. Should I have a nodejs api working in tandem with the react app ? I would prefer to only have one react app to keep it simple, but I'm wondering if it's actually possible.

Answer (score 0):

Cesium does not set CORS headers for its API. Therefore the browser is blocking the request. You have to use a proxy to access that endpoint.

For local development most tools like Webpack or Vite have a proxy built-in.